# Add multiple items into array and display array in textbox

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, textbox

I currently have a form which takes in 3 user inputs from 2 textboxes and 1 numericUpDown.

I want to be able to get the values put in here when a button is clicked, and display the value of all 3 into a seperate text box.

The issue arises when there is multiple additions.
I tried creating an array but it still only displays the last input.

```
        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newItem = NameTextBox.Text + "\t" +  QuantityBox.Value.ToString() + "\t" + PriceBox.Text;
        List<String> newItemList = new List<string>();
        newItemList.Add(newItem);
        for(int i = 0; i < newItemList.Count; i++)
        {
            BasketBox.Text = newItemList[i] + "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move the instantiation of `newItemList` outside of your `AddButton_Click` method. Each time you click the button you're creating a new list and losing the contents of the existing one.

Comment: You are overwriting `.Text` each time. concatenate instead: Change `BasketBox.Text = newItemList[i] + "\n"` to `BasketBox.Text += newItemList[i] + "\n";`

Comment: Move the `newItemList` declaration to outside of method. Or append to `Text` of  your textbox instead of replacing it. Read more about [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx). Or take a look at [`TextBox.AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Did you set the `Multiline` property off `Text Box` to true? I wrote it in my edit.

Comment: @MongZhu Yes the multiline property is set to true, and I have tried exactly what you have done, however it still only overwrites what was already written instead of going onto a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your list outside the function, so u can maintain the list of inputs,
and display updated list on every click.

```
List<String> newItemList = new List<string>();
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newItem = NameTextBox.Text + "\t" +  QuantityBox.Value.ToString()    + "\t" + PriceBox.Text;

    newItemList.Add(newItem);
    for(int i = 0; i < newItemList.Count; i++)
    {
        BasketBox.Text = newItemList[i] + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yepyepyep, Only issue I had which took me forever to figure out was that "\n" != "\r\n".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newItem = NameTextBox.Text + "\t" +  QuantityBox.Value.ToString() + "\t" + PriceBox.Text;
        List<String> newItemList = new List<string>();
        newItemList.Add(newItem);
        for(int i = 0; i < newItemList.Count; i++)
        {
            BasketBox.Text += newItemList[i] + "\n"; // this will add the text to your box
        }
    }
```

This will 'erase' old text in BasketBox:

```
BasketBox.Text = newItemList[i] + "\n"
```

This will add text in BasketBox:

```
BasketBox.Text += newItemList[i] + "\n"
```

Comment: This is very close! Thank you!

The issue is that it's not going onto a new line for some reason

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool method [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) which does the concatenation of string items from a list in one blow:

```
BasketBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, newItemList);
```

If you declare the list outside than each time the button is clicked an item will be added to it and all items will be displayed:

```
List<String> newItemList = new List<string>();

private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newItem = NameTextBox.Text + "\t" +  QuantityBox.Value.ToString() + "\t" + PriceBox.Text;
    newItemList.Add(newItem);
    BasketBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, newItemList);
}
```

Edit:

This of course will only work if you have set the property `Multiline` to true.